# Query performance with primary keys of different data types

Tags: postgresql

Is there a significant difference in performance if i decide to use INT or BIGINT as data type of a primary key in a table? Of course if i use BIGINT the value will have twice it's size. But as the primary key has always an index to speed up queries, is there going to be a significant difference in performance?

Comment: I am wondering if you could notice the difference.  But it is quite easy to set up a test for checking this.  Like `CREATE TABLE test_bigint AS SELECT i::bigint FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) t(i);` and then, after adding the index, do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Answer (score 0):

i would not see this as a major issue. of course things are a little larger but if we talk about a single integer column things will most likely be lost in noise anyway. we got 24 bytes of tuple header ... then comes the data. if things are 4 bytes larger? what difference does it make in a 10 column table.

so, no worries ... make sure that you do what is good for your app.